# Triangulate camera position and orientation in regards to known objects

Tags: object, design-patterns, camera, triangulation

I made an object tracker that calculates the position of an object recorded in a live camera feed using stereoscopic cameras. The math was simple, once you know the camera distance and orientation. However, now I thought it would be nice to allow me to quickly extract all these parameters, so when I change my setup or cameras I will be able to quickly calibrate it again.

To calculate the object position I made some simplifications/assumptions, which made the math easier: the cameras are in the same YZ plane, so there is only a distance in x between them. Their tilt is also just in the XY plane.
To reverse the triangulation I thought a test pattern (square) of 4 points of which I know the distances to each other would suffice. Ideally I would like to get the cameras' positions (distances to test pattern and each other), their rotation in X (and maybe Y and Z if applicable/possible), as well as their view angle (to translate pixel position to real world distances - that should be a camera constant, but in case I change cameras, it is quite a bit to define accurately)

I started with the same trigonometric calculations, but always miss parameters. I am wondering if there is an existing solution or a solid approach. If I need to add parameter (like distances, they are easy enough to measure), it's no problem (my calculations didn't give me any simple equations with that possibility though).
I also read about Homography in opencv, but it seems it applies to 2D space only, or not?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look for direct linear transformation (DLT) or space resection in combination with the collinearity equations.

Comment: @Grillteller: I think that's exactly what I looked for, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!